# How to store data in two places at the same time in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to store the same data at the same time to two different path/places in firebase real-time database? I tried this but it isn't working

```
export const DetailsCreated = ({ name }) => {
        return () => {
            firebase.database().ref('games')
            firebase.database().ref('users')
                .push({ name })

        };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [multi-location update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data). If you want to write the name under the same key in two places, that'd be:

```
var newKey = firebase.database().ref().push().key;

var updates = {};
updates['/games/' + newKey] = name;
updates['/users/' + newKey] = name;

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```